# CKEditor 5 Find Model Element By Attibute

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

A custom html dom element exists inside my editor:

```
<content id="1">
 <p>Paragraf is here and <a href="/url/to">link text</a> exists</p>
</content>
```

I want to find this element in the model using it's attributes. I can find it using a recursive method starting from root. But is there a simpler method like querySelectorAll?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've not found an out-of-the-box helper method which does this, but if anyone's just looking for a function definition they can use, try this:

```
function findDescendant (modelElement, predicate) {
  if (predicate(modelElement)) {
    return modelElement
  }
  if (modelElement.getChildren) {
    for (let child of modelElement.getChildren()) {
      const found = findDescendantByName(child, name)
      if (found) {
        return found
      }
    }
  }
}

...
...

const descendant = findDescendant(element, (element) => element.hasAttribute('foobar'))
```